# In OAuth2, why not always use the refresh token?

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

In OAuth2, to my understanding there is an `accessToken` - which expires after a relatively short time frame, and a `refreshToken` - which is used to generate a new `accessToken`.

My question is, why should I ever go through the trouble of checking whether the `accessToken` is valid or catching specific token expiry errors, instead of just getting a new `accessToken` every time with my `refreshToken`? Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

It is technically feasible but creates unnecessary requests to the OAuth server. You can instead do error handling for expired tokens and attempts to retrieve a access token using the refresh token if the you get a expiry error.

That way you do not need to call you Oauth server everytime (saves one request) and call the resource server only. Call the Oauth server only the first time and in case of expiry